# Mysterious error in SOAP when JAX-WS receives the response

Tags: java, soap, glassfish

I receive the following error when I'm trying to send a SOAP message. 
The thing that has me confused, is that it seems like

- Something fails in the C layer, the message *"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."* is a typical .net message if I recall.
- It happens deep in the SOAP handler.
- It happens when it receives the response.
- It looks to me that it actually fails, trying to create an error message.

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.2, with its default SOAP framework (JAX-WS if I recall)

Any pointers on how to trace this error, and possibly get the actual received SOAP response, to see if it is the one to blame?

I have to add that I'm NOT a SOAP expert by any means of the definition. I just have to figure our why this fails. Unfortunately.

Stack trace:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cuase of the failure.
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:134)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:177)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:256)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:151)
```

Comment: you sure deserve plus 1 for the title

Comment: I should probably see if I can make it more accurate. But I really am confused.

Answer (score 0):

This error is very hard to troubleshoot without any additional information like the SOAP request or the service WSDL.

Some things you can check in your code:

- are your objects properly initialized?
- do all attributes have the correct type?
- check for `null` values

Comment: The problem is that it have worked previously, and in tests.  I'm sending the request, and have confirmed it is correctly formatted, the problem seems to be in the reply from the server I'm talking to. This happens before the SOAP request returns to my own code. Are there any logger settings I can use to get the JAX-WS to dump more info?